# C char array insert characters using functions at different stages

Tags: c, insert, c-strings, memcpy

If I have a **char array** like: **char arr[32];**

Can I initialize it later on in **different functions** using **arr[0:5] = "00000"** and **arr[26:31] = "00000"**

If not, How can i insert different parts of strings to the char array later on?

Comment: Yes, you can. You need to write the code possibly using the `memcpy` function, eg. `memcpy(arr + 26, "00000", 5)`

Answer (score 1):

you can use memcpy for such purpose

```
int offset=5;
const char * str="000";
memcpy(arr+offset,str,strlen(str));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/):

```
char arr[35];
memcpy(&arr[0], "00000", 5);
memcpy(&arr[30], "00000", 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a separate function that performs the task.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * insert( char *dsn, size_t pos, size_t n, const char *src )
{
    memcpy( dsn + pos, src, n );
    return dsn;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 32 };
    char s[N] = "";
    const char *s1 = "AAAAA";
    const char *s2 = "BBBBB";

    puts( insert( s, 0, 5, s1 ) + 0 );

    puts( insert( s, 26, 5, s2 ) + 26 );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
AAAAA
BBBBB
```